# How can I secure properties of ViewController are initialized before/after some lifecycle events?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, xctest

For simple example, in my `ImageDetailViewController`, property `image`(it is `UIImage!`) must be initialized before end of `viewDidLoad` (in other words, before `viewWillAppear`).

I use `XCTAssertNotNil` on the first line of `viewWillAppear`.

How can I secure this behavior in unit test? or cannot?

EDIT:

If every initialization is processed in `viewDidLoad`, I can use Aaron's approach.
Can't I test some properties which is initialized out of its class(ex. previous controller's `prepareForSegue`)

Comment: Your test case is responsible for establishing any preconditions that are required for the test to be valid, so if you have properties that would normally be set by `prepareForSegue` then you should set these properties to appropriate values in your test case

Answer (score 1):

I did some tests. Here is how to trigger several different view cycle methods. I think the asserts speak for themselves.

```
class AppearanceTestDemoTests: XCTestCase {

  var sut: ViewController!

  override func setUp() {
    super.setUp()
    sut = ViewController()
  }

  func testLoading() {
    _ = sut.view

    XCTAssertTrue(sut.viewDidLoadGotCalled)
    XCTAssertFalse(sut.viewWillLayoutSubviewsGotCalled)
    XCTAssertFalse(sut.viewDidLayoutSubviewsGotCalled)
    XCTAssertFalse(sut.viewWillAppearGotCalled)
    XCTAssertFalse(sut.viewDidAppearGotCalled)
  }

  func testAppearance() {
    sut.beginAppearanceTransition(true, animated: false)
    sut.endAppearanceTransition()

    XCTAssertTrue(sut.viewDidLoadGotCalled)
    XCTAssertFalse(sut.viewWillLayoutSubviewsGotCalled)
    XCTAssertFalse(sut.viewDidLayoutSubviewsGotCalled)
    XCTAssertTrue(sut.viewWillAppearGotCalled)
    XCTAssertTrue(sut.viewDidAppearGotCalled)
  }

  func testLayout() {
    sut.view.layoutIfNeeded()

    XCTAssertTrue(sut.viewDidLoadGotCalled)
    XCTAssertTrue(sut.viewWillLayoutSubviewsGotCalled)
    XCTAssertTrue(sut.viewDidLayoutSubviewsGotCalled)
    XCTAssertFalse(sut.viewWillAppearGotCalled)
    XCTAssertFalse(sut.viewDidAppearGotCalled)
  }

  func testSegue() {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let sut = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController") as! ViewController

    sut.performSegueWithIdentifier("Foo", sender: nil)

    XCTAssertTrue(sut.prepareForSegueGotCalled)
  }
}
```

I pushed my demo project to [github](https://github.com/dasdom/AppearanceTestDemo).

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
let vc = ImageDetailViewController()
vc.view // loads view, triggering call to viewDidLoad()
XCTAssertNotNil(vc.image)
```

Comment: I have written some code which tests `loadView` and `viewDidLoad` before. Can I also test any other lifecycle event like `viewDidLayoutSubviews` or `viewDidAppear` in the same approach ?